# React native - copy file from ios project folder

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fs

I have files in assets folder which is created in Xcode under my_project/assets

I can normally access file in my template WebView with:

```
source={{uri: './assets/myfolder/index.html'}}
```

but I can't copy this file to DocumentsDirectory with react-native-fs:

```
RNFS.copyFile('./assets/myfolder/index.html', RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/index.html').then((result) => console.log('DONE')).catch((error) => console.log(error, 'ERROR'));
```

> Error: The file “index.html” couldn’t be opened because there is no
>   such file.

On android copyFileAssets works fine.